# How to draw in the border a straight line dividing it into 2 halves

Tags: c#, wpf, draw

I have a border in the wpf application.

1. How to draw in the border a straight line dividing it into 2 halves?
2. I have a handler for clicking on the border. How after MouseDown to draw a black point at the point of pressing(p.Y,p.X)? And how after pressing the second time to erase the old and draw a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For drawing a line to divide border, you can use Line or Polyline like this:

(you need to find your border hight and weight to get the half point, assume it's 200,300)

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            canvas.Children.Clear();
            Point[] points = new Point[2]
            {
            new Point(0,  100),
            new Point(300 , 100)
            };
            DrawLine(points);

        }

private void DrawLine(Point[] points)
        {
            Polyline line = new Polyline();
            PointCollection collection = new PointCollection();
            foreach (Point p in points)
            {
                collection.Add(p);
            }
            line.Points = collection;
            line.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            line.StrokeThickness = 1;
            canvas.Children.Add(line);
        }
```

for drawing a point, you can use Ellipse, and also use `e.GetPosition()` to get the possition of mouse click:

```
private void Window_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    \\ Remove the last object from the canvas
     if(Canvas.Children.Count>0)
    canvas.Children.RemoveAt(canvas.Children.Count-1);

    Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse();
    ellipse.Fill = Brushes.Sienna;
    ellipse.Width = 10;
    ellipse.Height = 10;
    ellipse.StrokeThickness = 2;

    canvas.Children.Add(ellipse);

    \\Set the position of the point.
    Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse, e.GetPosition(canvas).X);
    Canvas.SetTop(ellipse, e.GetPosition(canvas).Y);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Everything is working.
Tell me more please, how to limit the analysis of clicks only in our area 200x200?

Comment: Welcome. try to define a canvas in that area and put your code in the MouseLeftButtonDown event of that canvas.